# Why is my SMO Query returning -1 for each GO statement?

Tags: c#, sql, smo

I am using Microsoft's SMO (SQL Server Management Objects) to execute a SQL script that contains `GO` Statements, since the regular System.Data.SqlClient does not recognize `GO` as a command.  It is actually running fine (I think..) but it seems to be returning a -1 for every GO Statement.  So with the following code..

```
using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     try
     {
         cnn.Open();
         Console.WriteLine("Connection Successful!");                    
         var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(cnn));
         var rows = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlStuff.CommandText);                    
         Console.WriteLine($"Script Successful: {rows} affected");
         Console.ReadLine();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect to Server: " + ex.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
     }
}
```

my console reads "Script Successful: -47 affected", which after looking at my script is the exact number of `GO`s I have.  Is that normal for my query to return a -1 for each `GO`?  I can't seem to find documentation on it, and it concerns me that part of my query is not executing correctly even though at this time it seems to have generated the tables I need.  It is my first time using SMO and I just need to make sure this is normal.

Comment: what does your query look like..? can you edit your question and post the Sql query..?

Comment: That's strange, but I think it's normal. [The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199350.aspx) says "specifies the total number of rows affected by the Transact-SQL command for UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1." -- so I guess it's summing all the -1s together. Which is not exactly "correct".. but I wouldn't worry if your statements seem to have executed.

Comment: @MethodMan I can, but its almost 400 rows and would take up more of this post than what I think is necessary.

Comment: @Blorgbeard yes, that is what I read as well, but it just seemed odd and almost a bit backwards that a negative number represented success.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: if you are unsure if your statements are executing correctly, wrap inside of a transaction or create a logtable and log all of the sql and entries into the table

Comment: -1 is a common sentinel value, and using it makes sense because it can't be interpreted as a count (where, for example, 0 could). Summing them however, does not make sense. Especially if you had a mix of statements some of which you expected a count from and some you expected just "success". Then your total rows affected would be off by the number of non-count statements.

Comment: @Blorgbeard That is why I thought it would be odd to mix the two.  There is a summation of the executions, which, if mixed with update/insert/delete, would return a bad value.  Feel free to create an answer and I'll accept it.